# Compiling C# code at runtime under mono fails when referencing Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: c#, json.net, mono

our software is written in `C#` running `.Net-Framework 4.7.2`. Our users can use a script editor built into our software to write their own user scripts with C#. To realize that, we are using the .Net component `CodeDomProvider`. To make it possible to work with JSON in an easy way, we want to make `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` be referenced in our user's scripts. This is done by adding the reference to the CompilerParameters of the CodeDomProvider. The Newtonsoft.Json is added to my application by the usage of the newest Newtonsoft.Json `NuGet` package (12.0.3).

Here a minimum example of this setup:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;

namespace ScriptingUnix
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string output;
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
                {
                    output = "/tmp/MyUnixTest.dll";
                }
                else
                {
                    output = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyUnixTest.dll");
                }

                CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters
                {
                    GenerateInMemory = false,
                    IncludeDebugInformation = true,
                    OutputAssembly = output
                };

                using (CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
                {
                    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
                    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource
                    (
                        parameters, 
                        "using System;\nusing Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;\nusing Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;\n class Program\r\n{\r\n    static void Main(string[] args)\r\n    {\r\n        \r\n    }\r\n}"
                    );

                    foreach (CompilerError compilerError in results.Errors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(compilerError);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This setup works fine under .Net Framework on Windows. The problem is, that we are also providing a version of our software running with Mono on (Arch)-Linux (Linux 4.19.80-1-ARCH armv7l, Mono JIT compiler version 6.0.0 (makepkg/6256b82d62f Wed 25 Sep 2019 05:04:08 AM UTC)), where running the same code with mono results in an `error CS0006: Metadata file Newtonsoft.Json.dll could not be found`.

I already tried to add the following to the app.conf of my application, but that did not help. Also reinstalling the `NuGet` package did not help. Adding the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` to the GAC does not work (fails with `Failure adding assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the cache: The file specified is not a valid assembly.`). While trying around with the app.conf I observed the error message changed to `error CS0009: Metadata file /opt/Newtonsoft.Json.dll does not contain valid metadata: Metadata file /opt/Newtonsoft.Json.dll does not contain valid metadata`. That's why I guess he finds the dll but needs additional, valid meatadata. I thought about some sort of dll.conf.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Does anyone have a hint on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilites:

1. Use latest Mono (6.6) from github. Compile it if package not avaliable.
2. Downgrade Newtonsoft.Json to version 11.0.  Use binding redirect if nessecary.

Comment: Why do you think that this will solve the problem? Which changes in Mono 6.6 in comparison to Mono 6.0.0 or Newtonsoft.Json 11.0 to 12.0.3 should have changed the behavior?

Comment: Because I tested and this solves the issue. Maybe dll format has changed and new mono  has added supprot for new format.

Comment: I just retested it with using the 11.0.2 and made binding redirects to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />`. Now it works as intended. Thank you very much @Andrus

Comment: In my case, had to stay at Newtonsoft.Json 12. Updated mono in container to latest (6.8). Working again. Phew! Glad I found this thread! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Your code example works well on .NET 4.7, but since you're running Mono here are some possible solutions for you:

Compiler needs to know where to get this file.
If you say that you need to reference `System.dll` - compiler probably tries to find it in [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) (and it does find it).
When you reference unknown library like `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` it tries to search GAC and fails. Then it's probably trying to find it in working directory, [etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)..

#### Solution #1:

Try to set full path to your library;

#### Solution #2:

Try to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac) `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in the GAC;

#### Solution #3:

Try .NET Core! It's amazing, cross-platform and 3.1 version now has open source WinForms and WPF!

I know that moving your code to .NET Core 3 takes time but still it's worth it.

Comment: From the error message I would guess he finds the Newtonsoft.Json.dll but he want to have some additional metadata. I also tried adding the dll to the GAC, but gacutil reported: `Failure adding assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll to the cache: The file specified is not a valid assembly.`.
Switching to .net Core is planned but not yet possible, so this is not a solution for me. Will update the question based on your remarks.